# Why to answer a question post acceptance

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Most of the times, the OP moves on from a question he/she has asked to another question, once an answer that suits the needs of the OP is found. This is done by accepting the answer which helped the OP.

Suppose I happen to stumble upon a question like that, and feel that I could give a better answer to that question(yep, better than the already accepted answer), should I just go ahead and post an answer? SO allows the poster of the question to be able to change the accepted answer, but will the OP really come back to the question to have a look at my answer and actually consider it?

Because, psychologically even I would get bogged down if my answer(which is really better than the accepted answer) just goes unnoticed, as it would never get upvoted and nobody would really bother to look at the answers posted till the very last.

How should I make that conscious decision of whether I should post a new answer to an already accepted question or not?!

Comment: If you have an answer that is truely different, go ahead an answer.  If it is good, the community will upvote it.  Then the answer will be there for someone who has the same problem in the future.

Comment: For what it's worth, I went ahead and posted an answer to a question that already had an accepted answer for almost 2 years, because the accepted answer was incorrect. Just as I suspected, the OP is still active on the site but has chosen to ignore my answer instead of accepting it, despite the fact that [it's already earned me Populist over the accepted but incorrect answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107). The accepted answer is still gaining upvotes, but since I have Populist over it I probably shouldn't complain, right?

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Yeah agreed. But its the general tendency of users to not scroll till the end(answers with 0 upvotes are present there) to look for an answer. They generally stick with the accepted answer or simply move on(if the top 3-4 answers don't help them), thinking that when the top 3-4 answers didn't help, of what use will the other answers be.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - So you'd suggest that no matter what, I go ahead and post the answer(even if the OP chooses to ignore my answer)? Well, we can agrue that you're a mod, with a high rep, so people took of your notice of an answer by you. But that wouldn't be the case everytime, would it?

Comment: @R.J if you don't think anyone will see it, then don't answer it... I just gave you my opinion :-) and Bolt Clock's experience is probably similar to dozens of other answers too.  Good stuff gets voted up, sometimes it just takes longer.

Comment: @psubsee2003- Don't take me wrong. I appreciate your opinion and that is exactly why I've posted this question to make a conscious decision about it, based on the experience of you folks here :)

Comment: @R.J: If you're confident in your answer, go ahead and post it. I can't tell you the exact odds that it'll be well-received by the community, but it doesn't hurt to try. Just remember that users do see and vote on content. Also, it would take *a lot* of scrolling down that answer to find out that a high-rep user posted it so I wouldn't even consider that argument... I like to believe more people voted on it for its sheer length alone than my rep.

Comment: @Downvoter - Care to comment? I would love to hear your opinion too!

Comment: Also, don't forget that just because an answer has been accepted that doesn't mean it can't be unaccepted in favour of a better answer. Answers get unaccepted and another chosen in its place quite often. It's highly possible that if your answer *is* better then the OP may well choose to accept your answer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you add  an answer to a question, the asker is notified - with a red symbol in the inbox if they sign in, and with an email if they asked for one. They may return and change their acceptance to your answer, or they may not. I have certainly seen the accept move many times.

But even if they don't, if you think you have a useful answer to offer you should offer it. It may help others who have that problem. There is even a badge for writing an answer that gets a much better score than a good accepted answer. That's a clue to you that the behavior is encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

OP is not the only one who reads a question. Especially on smaller Stack Exchange sites questions indeed do get attention from other users, too. If your answer brings something new to the topic, why wouldn't you share? Over time it will get you some upvotes and response. My question asked Jun 6, 2013 still gets votes - as do answers to it, even the ones that are not accepted.